# Why do coders load a class twice?

Tags: java

In the class `Myclass` the class `Help` is loaded as an object but then it's loaded again in the `Help` class itself. Isn't the `Help` class loaded twice? What is the reason for doing so?

For example:

```
public class Myclass {
    int i;
    Object help;

    public Myclass()  {
        help = new Help(); /// help class loaded
    }

    private Object doSomething(int h)  {
        Help.getHelp(h);
    }
}
```

Help class:

```
public class Help(){
    Object returnhelp;
    int h;

    public Help()   {
        int h=3;
    }

    public Help getHelp(int y)  {
        return new Help(y);    ///// Help class loaded again ????
    }

    private add(int y)  {
        h=+y;
        return h;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do `new Help()` the class isn't being loaded, it's being instantiated, there's a big difference.

Comment: doSomething misses a `return`. `getHelp` should be `public static Help`. That would make `getHelp` a **factory** method. In general one would decide for the one or for the other, making the constructor private. If you place the factory method in another class you can entirely hide the actual class, and return an interface. So you have the freedom of electing an implementation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think your question has been answered. Please [mark an answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is not loaded twice, but twice instantiated as an object.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) is the high level view from the Java tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

First you're confusing class loading with class instantiation.

- Class loading is when the Java Virtual Machine loads the class code into memory.
- Class instantiation is when you create an instance (an object) of that class.

Besides, your code cannot compile because in order to do this

```
Help.getHelp(h)
```

`getHelp(int)` has to be static:

```
public static Help getHelp(int y)
```

In this case you're not instantiating twice. Using a static method to instantiate objects for a given class is a common procedure, and it's called a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29).

Comment: There's also a compilation error in the `getHelp(int y)` method, because the `Help` class doesn't implement a constructor that takes an int argument.

Comment: Yes, there are quite a few errors in that code actually. I'm trying to stick to the question anyway :)

Comment: I was about to comment the same thing! ;-)
Also.. I'm not sure what `Object returnhelp` is doing there..

Answer (score 1):

The `Help` class is loaded once. However, you are probably creating more instance of it. One is created in the `Myclass` constructor, another one is created when calling the `Help.getHelp()` method.

Comment: Why would one be doing so? creating two instances?